# Sorting org files in Emacs Dired on the basis of the org time stamp in the file itself

Tags: org-mode, dired, time-date, sorting

Is there a way of sorting org files (.org) in Emacs Dired on the basis of the org time stamp in the file itself. With every org file I create, I insert an org time stamp near the top of the file. This time stamp may or may not reflect the day on which the document was created or last modified. For e.g. if I have to give a lecture, the org file is dated to the day of the lecture. I am aware that Dired generally uses the ls program.

Comment: Can you give an example of one of these files? I assume, also, that the timestamp is not in the name of the file?

Comment: Rather than customizing dired, you might look at [Deft](https://jblevins.org/projects/deft/). This package allows you to filter a directory of files by typing a string that matches file text. Checkout the [screencast](https://jblevins.org/projects/deft/deft-v0.6.gif).

Comment: Correct. The timestamp is only in the file. An example is:

#+TITLE: Aristotle's Ethics
<2019-11-15 Fri>

Comment: I do use Deft--a mainstay of my workflow. However, this would not suit my purposes here. It is not that I am wanting to find a file of a certain date but order files sequentially.